# Magento 2 - Import .CSV "503 - Unavailable"

Tags: magento2, import, csv

I've just recently installed Magento 2.0.7 using Ubuntu 14.04.1.

I'm trying to import a .CSV file, provided from my wholesaler who also uses Magento.

When I try and import the .CSV, I see in my Firebug console "NetworkError: 503 Service Unavailable"

My Magento install is located at `/var/www/html/magento/` and I'm trying to import the products into `/var/www/html/magento/media/import` which is a directory I've created myself, with `755` permissions.

There are no errors shown in Magento `debug` or `system`, `apache2.log` or `mysql.log`.

I have no idea why this isn't working - being new to Magento I don't know what other logs to look in to. This is using a Digital Ocean image, Ubuntu 14.04.1 using Magento 2.0.7

Thanks for your time

Edit:

Here is my directory structure - `/var/www/html/magento` is as follows:

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Jul 18 20:49 app
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Jul 18 20:49 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 440415 Jul 18 20:49 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1849 Jul 18 20:47 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 320677 Jul 18 20:49 composer.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   3425 Jul 18 20:49 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10011 Jul 18 20:49 CONTRIBUTOR_LICENSE_AGREEMENT.html
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    631 Jul 18 20:49 COPYING.txt
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Jul 18 20:49 dev
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   2926 Jul 18 20:49 Gruntfile.js
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1358 Jul 18 20:49 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Jul 18 20:49 lib
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10376 Jul 18 20:49 LICENSE_AFL.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  10364 Jul 18 20:49 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   4108 Jul 18 20:49 nginx.conf.sample
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   1427 Jul 18 20:49 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    804 Jul 18 20:49 php.ini.sample
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Jul 18 20:49 phpserver
drwxrwxrwx  6 root root   4096 Jul 18 20:49 pub
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root   4096 Jul 18 20:49 setup
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root   4096 Jul 18 20:47 update
drwxrwsrwx 10 root root   4096 Sep 28 18:47 var
drwxrwsr-x 28 root root   4096 Jul 18 20:50 vendor
```

I am also using the same .csv Magento makes available to download, to clarify there are no issues with my document.

Comment: Have you try to import product using magento 2 default functionlity from admin?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Yes, that's what I'm trying to do via the admin panel. I can see the error message in Firebugs console.

Comment: Have you see any error on admin screen?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Unfortunately no, it just shows the animated loading GIF. I suspect the issue may be the owner of my /var/www/html/magento. The current owner is root, should it be the magento user, or www-data?

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to take a look on the recommended directory ownership and permissions: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Running under the root user is not a good practice.

Second, if you used a vhost for your apache server and specified a custom error log file, check that one for errors with tail -f /var/log/apache2/your_custom_file . You can also tail -f /var/log/apache2/* and search for errors.

Third, try to check `MAGENTO2_ROOT/var/log/exception.log` .